# iOS - NSURLConnection connections to more than 5 different IPs over LAN

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection

My app tries to determine the IP of a web server located on the same LAN when it starts up.

It works out the IP range to scan, and uses `NSURLConnection` objects with a 1 second time out to determine whether an IP is reachable, and if it is, try to call a service on it, if the service call is successful then we know we've found the correct IP.

The problem though is that the app cannot open more than 5 connections at a time, even though all the connections have different IPs to connect to. I would get about a dozen connections firing off but the rest will just report `The request timed out.` without ever leaving the device.

I have read that this restriction applies to `NSURLConnection` connections to a single IP address, but as I said, each connection has its own different IP.

I have also tried using the `SCNetworkReachability` to determine whether an IP is reachable but all it tells me is that the IP addresses on the LAN are reachable, in theory, without making an actual connection.

Are there reliable ways to connect to more IPs at a time?

Answer (score 0):

Every operating system maintains a maximum number of sockets per process. I couldn't find an authoritative source for iOS, but it would make sense for Apple to keep that number very low and five seems to be a common answer by others trying this.

You may want to look at `NSOperationQueue` to manage the connections (see [Asynchronous HTTP Client Using NSOperationQueue](http://www.icodeblog.com/2012/10/19/tutorial-asynchronous-http-client-using-nsoperationqueue/)) or use [`AFNetworking`](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) to do all the real work.

Comment: I do use NSOperationQueue to manage the connections, but if I set the queue's `maxConcurrentOperationCount` to anything larger than 5 the app will start timing out connections without attempting them. I tried using `sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:` on NSURLConnection to add them to the queue; I tried using `addOperationWithBlock:`, and in the block I use `sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:`; I tried invoking the async calls without the queue and handle the call backs; no luck for any of these approaches. I will look into `AFNetworking`

Comment: @AllenZeng AFNetworking will not help here. You need to utilize lower level APIs (CFNetwork) or even sockets. A totally other approach - but may solve your problem - is this: [Bonjour](https://developer.apple.com/bonjour/).

Comment: @CouchDeveloper indeed Bonjour is the solution. No need for brute force scanning.